# Linearity of a system to biomedical applications

Tags: linear-systems, non-linear

Suppose $x(t)$ is temperature and $y(t)$ is sweat. If the following equation describes the system, answer if is it linear or not.
$y(t) = [H(x)](t)$ . I would say that it isn't linear because we dont know explicitly the function $H$, for example $H(t)=e^t$

Comment: Yeah. If you don’t have the actual input-ouput relationship, how are you supposed to answer this? Your intuition is probably correct. I know I sweat a lot less going from 5 to 25 degrees (Celsius) than from 25 to 45…

Comment: Yes, I made the same thought, this was an exams question on a interdeparmental Msc BME, but what really confused me was the notation $[H(x)](t)$, why $t$ is outside of function, could this denote that $t$ is the only variable, thus to apply the linearity proof independently from $H(x)$. My intuition said, that this notation is equivalent to $H(x(t))$

Comment: This is probably a notational thing.  $\left [ H(x) \right ](t)$ _probably_ means the same thing as the system $y(t) = h(x, t)$, where $h$ describes a general system that operates on the signal $x(t)$ and coughs up $y(t)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that $y(t) = \left [ H(x) \right](t)$ means "the system $H$ operates on the signal $x(t)$ to generate the signal $y(t)$", then just the $y(t) = \left [ H(x) \right](t)$ doesn't imply a linear system.

However, think about it:

- It's really freaking cold, you don't sweat, or you sweat at some minimal level to keep your skin oiled and hydrated.  You certainly don't notice yourself sweating.
- It's moderately cold -- still no noticeable sweat.
- It's moderately hot -- you sweat a bit.
- It's very hot -- you sweat a lot.
- It's very very hot -- you sweat a lot, but not much more than when it was very hot -- you may even overheat and stop sweating.

If you enjoy the macabre, bookend my list with "you die, and then you don't sweat at all".

I suspect that you could readily find a reference that gives you a curve of typical core body temperature vs. the rate of sweating.  When you do, I suspect that you'll see that the curve starts out flat at low temperature, deflects upward and climbs, then deflects downward -- and if I'm right about heat exhaustion or heat stroke or whatever it's called, at some point you *stop sweating* and either receive some sort of intervention or you die.

That curve would prove nonlinearity.